# Sidekiq + Redistogo (on Heroku) - ERR max number of clients reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I'm getting the error "ERR max number of clients reached" from Redis on Heroku and I'm not sure why that is. I'm using Sidekiq for background workers and I have the concurrency for that set to 5. Is there something I'm missing that's causing the connections to go over? I'm on the free Redistogo plan and I realize it only allows up to 10 connections but I'm wondering why it's going over that 10 in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer inside of the Sidekiq docs:

```
Heroku "ERR max number of clients reached"

You've hit the max number of Redis connections allowed by your plan.

Limit the number of redis connections per process in config/sidekiq.yml. For example, if you're on Redis To Go's free Nano plan and want to use the Sidekiq web client, you'll have to set the concurrency down to 3.

:concurrency:  3
```